# Passing an expression tree as a parameter to another expression tree in EntityDataModel

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two expression trees defined like this:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> BoolExpression { get; }
```

and

```
Expression<Func<Customer, string>> PropertyExpression { get; }
```

I need to create a new expression tree that will result in the equivalent of:

```
Customer c = null;
var expression = e1(e2(c));
```

I can do it with Compile(), Invoke():

```
Customers c = null;
var e3 = e1.Compile().Invoke(e2.Compile().Invoke(c));
```

But I can't use Compile or Invoke methods because I'm using EntityDataModel. When I pass "expression" to Where method it converts to SQL-query and passed to database.

P.S.: I want to do some kind of Query builder using EntityDataModel. There are n-fields and m-conditions. I want to define n-expressions for fields and m-expressions for conditions and then combine them.

Comment: This is actually a surprisingly difficult thing to do in order to make it compatible with EF as you have to compose a new expression from the body of the two expressions you have. You can't simple create a new expression with one calling the other. Will try and write a proper answer for this when I'm not on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Give this a try first - I just tried it with LINQ-to-SQL and it works so it should work in EF. It's not a million miles from what you had, just saying invoke e1 with the result of invoking e2:

```
var e3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(Expression.Invoke(e1, Expression.Invoke(e2, e2.Parameters)), e2.Parameters);
```

**Option 2**

I had thought you would need to walk the expression tree and replace the usage of the String parameter in the BoolExpression func, something like this:

```
// replace parameter use anywhere in e1.Body with e2.Body
var remover = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(e2.Body);
var bb = remover.Visit(e1.Body);

// create a new lambda with our amended body but still with e2 parameters i.e. the Customer
var e3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(bb, e2.Parameters);

public class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    Expression _replace;

    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(Expression replace)
    {
        _replace = replace;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        // when we encounter a parameter replace it
        return _replace;
    }
}
```

Obviously if you introduce more than one parameter into your expressions things get a bit more complicated.

Comment: Option 1: 
I try it with EntityDataModel and get exception: "Node type "Invoke" of LINQ expression not supported by LINQ to Entities."

Option 2:
This works great. Thanks.

Comment: Why does that not surprise me, MS seem to have gone with sorting out the features the minority of users want instead of making sure it has parity with LINQ-to-SQL which is what the majority use it for.

Comment: The second solution worked for me as well. It has been over 10 years. Is there a better solution now?